# Prove that a set spans the space of M2x2

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to prove the next set spans the space M2x2:
$$S=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\1 & 1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\-1 & 1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\2 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$
So:
$$C1\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\1 & 1\end{bmatrix}+C2\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\-1 & 1\end{bmatrix}+ C3\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\2 & 1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}$$
The equations to solve this problem give me:
$$\begin{bmatrix}c1+c2+c3  & c1+c3\\c1-c2+2c3 & c1+c2+c3\end{bmatrix},$$

I'm stuck in this point because I don't know how to express that this set doesn't span the M2x2 space since Column 1 row 1 and Column 2 row 2 are exactly the same value hence I can't form all M2x2 space. What's the formal way I can prove my reasoning.

Comment: Hint 1: Try to find a linear combination of $S$ that produces $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: You can conclude that, for example, $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ is not in the span of S.

Comment: Hint 2: How many scalars do you need to specify a matrix in $\operatorname{span}S$?  How many do you need in general to specify a matrix in $M_{2\times 2}$?

Answer (score 4):

So you got $$c_1+c_2+c_3=a\\ c_1+c_3=b\\c_1-c_2+2c_3=c \\ c_1+c_2+c_3=d$$
The next step is to show $c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4$ in terms of $a,b,c,d$
You can use elementary row operations to do this.
If there is always a solution, then the set span the space; if there is a choice of $a,b,c,d$ for which the system is inconsistent, then the vectors do not span the space.

Comment: Reducing the matrix I get 
$$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 1 & 3a-2b\\0 & 1 & 0& a-b\\0 & 0 & 1 & 6a-4b-c\\1 & 1 & 1 & d\end{bmatrix}$$, from this I get C3=3a-2b=6a-4b-c from this can I assume this is inconsistent?

Answer (score 1):

The space $\mathcal M_{2\times 2}$ is of dimension $4$ and since any span set contains a basis so its cardinal is greater or equal $4$, hence $S$ isn't a span set of this vector space.

Answer (score 0):

"I'm stuck in this point because I don't know how to express that this set doesn't span the M2x2 space since Column 1 row 1 and Column 2 row 2 are exactly the same value hence I can't form all M2x2 space. What's the formal way I can prove my reasoning."

To clean up your language.
$C_1, C_2, C_3$ spans the set of matrices of the form $\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&a\end{pmatrix}$. These matricies are a proper subset of $M_{2\times2}$